Combine two calls into a single one
Given a username, I need to create a review for this user. Here is the code:
export async function create(
  values: FormSchema,
  username: string,
  ownerId: string,
) {
  const user = await db.query.users.findFirst({
    where: eq(users.username, username),
  })

  await db.insert(reviews).values({ ...values, userId: user.id, ownerId })
}

And here is my schema:
export const users = pgTable(
  'user',
  {
    id: text('id').primaryKey(),
    ...
  }
)

export const usersRelations = relations(users, ({ many }) => ({
  reviewsLeft: many(reviews, { relationName: 'review_to_owner' }),
  reviewsReceived: many(reviews, { relationName: 'review_to_user' }),
}))

export const reviews = pgTable('review', {
  id: text('id').primaryKey(),
  ...

  ownerId: text('ownerId')
    .notNull()
    .references(() => users.id),
  userId: text('userId')
    .notNull()
    .references(() => users.id)
})

export const reviewsRelations = relations(reviews, ({ one }) => ({
  user: one(users, {
    fields: [reviews.userId],
    references: [users.id],
    relationName: 'review_to_user',
  }),
  owner: one(users, {
    fields: [reviews.ownerId],
    references: [users.id],
    relationName: 'review_to_owner',
  }),
}))

Is there a way to combine these two calls into a single one? For example, with prisma it could be as easy as:

export async function create(
  values: FormSchema,
  username: string,
  ownerId: string,
) {
  await prisma.review.create({
    data: { ...values, ownerId },
    where: { user: { username } },
  })
}

And is there any difference between these two examples in terms of performance, number of DB calls, etc.? I don't mind writing a few more lines of code, just wondering if my code could be better optimized. I'd like to understand if I'm using drizzle correctly.
